# How to reshape a multidimensional array from a particular arrangement to another arrangement?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensor

I have a `before_arr`(2 x 3 x 4) multidimensional array. I want to turn it into a `new_arr` (3 x 2 x 4) with a specific arrangement pattern which I wrote below.

```
import numpy as np

before_arr = np.array([
    [
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     ],
    [
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     ],
    ], dtype=float)

# what I want
new_arr = np.array([
    [
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     ],
    [
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     ],
    [
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     ],
    ], dtype=float)
```

`before_arr.reshape(3, 2, 4)` doesn't give me what I want.

```
In [74]: before_arr.reshape(3, 2, 4)
Out[74]:
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: `arr.transpose(1,0,2)` probably does what you want.

Comment: Whoa @hpaulj can you explain how that works? The doc says `For an n-D array, if axes are given, their order indicates how the axes are permuted ` but it's not clear what that means

Comment: `2,1,0` is a full transpose, `0,1,2` doesn't change anything. `1,0,2` switches the first 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to swap the position of two axes, you can use `np.swapaxes`.  This is probably the most straightforward approach to get your desired output.

```
before_arr.swapaxes(0, 1)
```

```
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

In a more general sense, you can use `transpose` to explicitly define an ordering of axes for your desired output, which would be beneficial if you needed to move more than one axis (although not strictly required here).

```
before_arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to match respective rows.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

before_arr = np.array([
    [
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     ],
    [
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     ],
    ], dtype=float)

new_arr = np.array([*zip(*before_arr)])
print(new_arr)
```

Output:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]]
```

Comment: can you explain what * does to the np.ndarray?

Comment: @Alby it is an iterable unpacking. see [pep-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). it unpacks the array on its top level (the  dim of size 2) to 2  different elements, each an array with shape 3x4, and passes them top zip.

Comment: and the out `*` right before `zip` and the surroinding `[` `]`could just be replaced with `list` actually...